# add content reference to product in drupal commerce

Tags: commerce, nodes, entities

how can I add content reference to commerce product?
consider your product is mobile phone, and you don't want to enter add specifications of the phone, just make content type of phone, make phone contents and reference them in product.
is there a better way? because I couldn't reference content in product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution anyway:

Using EntityReference module this can be done!! you just add an entityreference field to your product and then in settings you choose your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

The most usual is adding a field of type *Product reference* on your content type.

In fact it's a entity reference but drupal commerce manage all the dependencies and definitions.